# using subprocess.run the program doesn't work, but copying the text from the run([xxx]) does work. any suggestions

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I have written a short bit of code to run a program (cutadapt) on multiple files. however it gives the following error for each of the files it tries to run: "cutadapt: error: unrecognized arguments". 
Run on MacOS, python 3.7.3,

If I print the statement in the same program, copy that as a single call in the terminal, then it does work. Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```py
import glob

import subprocess

fastq_folder = "/path/2019.01_spades_output_pathodetect/FASTQ_trimming"

listoffiles = glob.glob(fastq_folder + "/*.gz")

for fastq in listoffiles:
    input_file = fastq
    output_file = fastq.replace("_001.fastq.gz", "_001CUT20.fastq.gz")
    output_file = fastq.replace("2019.01_spades_output_pathodetect/FASTQ_trimming/", "2019.01_spades_output_pathodetect/FASTQ_trimming/CUT20/")
    print("cutadapt", "--cut 20", "-o", output_file, input_file)
    subprocess.run(["cutadapt", "--cut 20", "-o", output_file, input_file])
```

**so the output in the terminal is:**

```
cutadapt --cut 20 -o /path/2019.01_spades_output_pathodetect/FASTQ_trimming/CUT20/AWGS09281_S20_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz /path/2019.01_spades_output_pathodetect/FASTQ_trimming/AWGS09281_S20_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
Run "cutadapt --help" to see command-line options.
See https://cutadapt.readthedocs.io/ for full documentation.

cutadapt: error: unrecognized arguments: /path/2019.01_spades_output_pathodetect/FASTQ_trimming/AWGS09281_S20_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
```

**Then, when I copy the printed statement, it works:**

```
cutadapt --cut 20 -o /path/2019.01_spades_output_pathodetect/FASTQ_trimming/CUT20/AWGS09281_S20_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz /path/2019.01_spades_output_pathodetect/FASTQ_trimming/AWGS09281_S20_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz


This is cutadapt 2.3 with Python 3.7.3
Command line parameters: --cut 20 -o /path/2019.01_spades_output_pathodetect/FASTQ_trimming/CUT20/AWGS09281_S20_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz /path/2019.01_spades_output_pathodetect/FASTQ_trimming/AWGS09281_S20_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
Processing reads on 1 core in single-end mode ...
[   8<-------] 00:00:06       490,635 reads  @     13.6 µs/read;   4.42 M reads/minute
Finished in 6.71 s (14 us/read; 4.39 M reads/minute).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separate *all* the arguments; `"--cut 20"` passes a single argument containing both the switch and its value (that it, it tells program it received a single switch named `cut 20`). You'd only pass it as a single argument if, at the command line, you literally passed `"--cut 20"` in quotes to prevent the whitespace from breaking it up into separate pieces of the program's `argv` (which you clearly don't in your example).

Split it up to `"--cut", "20"` and it should work.

Comment: Lighting fast! it indeed solved the problem.  thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Your code passes `--cut 20` to cutadapt as a single argument, which it apparently can't handle.  (From cutadapt's argument parser's point of view, it probably thinks you're trying to specify an option named "`cut 20`", which doesn't exist.)  You need to split the argument in two:

```
subprocess.run(["cutadapt", "--cut", "20", "-o", output_file, input_file])
```